# Remover tipo quando valor for 0

Tags: css

Tenho o [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) instalado em meu Visual Studio, e ele me fez a seguinte recomendação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logo, removi o tipo da unidade. O estilo funcionou perfeitamente no Chrome, mas ao testar no Firefox e IE, ele foi considerado inválido.

Código de exemplo:

```css
.mydiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(0, red, yellow);
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv"></div>
```

Seria mesmo uma boa prática remover o tipo da unidade do CSS quando o valor for 0?

Existe alguma outra alternativa a não ser inserir o tipo da unidade?

Comment: "ele foi considerado inválido" Com isso você quer dizer que rolou algum erro no console ou que o gradiente não funcionou?

Comment: que o gradiente não funcionou... Sem mensagem no console, mas o [Firefox avisa o motivo](http://i.imgur.com/lNeXFvo.jpg)

Comment: No edge funcionou pra mim, testando o snippet.

Comment: @Edilson Eu li IE na publicação e interpretei como Edge, falha minha.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, então para funcionar em outros navegadores segue abaixo um exemplo:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #77e859 , #8ec982); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #77e859, #8ec982); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #77e859, #8ec982); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
```

E a unidade, creio eu que não tem problema colocar o **0**.

Tomará que isso ajuda você a funcionar em outros navegadores...

```css
.mydiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(0, red, yellow);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0, red, yellow); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(0, red, yellow); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(0, red, yellow); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv"></div>
```

## Referências

- [CSS3 Gradients](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)

Comment: @nathn muito obrigado pela resposta, o gradiente apareceu, mas está com o ângulo invertido. O estranho é que olhando [nesse exemplo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient#Cross-browser_gradients) na documentação da Mozilla, eles fizeram a ultima linha com um parâmetro invertido, e agora fiquei um pouco mais confuso.